# With providedIn: 'any' and providedIn: NgModule now deprecated are there any other options other than root?

Tags: angular, angular-services

Across Angular v14 and v15 releases, the `providedIn: 'any'` and `ProvidedIn: NgModule` are now deprecated. Is `'root'` now the only valid value for `providedIn`? I realize that you still have the option of using `NgModule.providers`, so my question isn't about how to provide services at the module level, my question is specifically about the `ProvidedIn` attribute. Are there any options remaining other than `'root'`? If not I wonder if this attribute will disappear completely. In other words, I wonder if all services in the future will default to the `providedIn: 'root'` unless they are provided in the module definition (`NgModule.providers`). This is just me wondering, not part of the question per se.

Relatedly, if a service is provided by `NgModule.providers`, my understanding is that it is not tree-shakeable. But I presume these services will still be lazily loaded if they are provided by a lazy-loaded module?

Comment: I'll try and find actual sources so I can convert this to an answer, but yes, `providedIn: 'root'` or including the service in the `providers` array of an `NgModule` or standalone `Component` are the only real options now (you can still manually add them to a custom injector, but that's such a niche approach). My understanding is that services provided in `NgModule.providers` are lazy if the modules are lazy, but not tree-shakable. I'd have to check on `Component.providers`, but wouldn't be surprised if the Angular team managed to add tree-shaking here since it's a newer approach.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `null`, `'root'`, and `'platform'` are [all still valid and not yet deprecated](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#options).

Comment: Ah. I wasn't aware of `'platform'`. Looking at the docs you linked, am I understanding that that provides a service to multiple angular applications exposed on the same page?

Comment: Correct, if you were to bootstrap multiple applications, `providedIn: 'platform'` would provide a singleton for the whole tab (to each of the bootstrapped applications). This is also a fairly niche approach and I've only ever seen it for things like providing a chat app that's not dependent on the main app and should always preserve state regardless of the navigation/errors going on in the main app.

Comment: [Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgj2fg?file=src/main.ts) with two bootstrapped applications. Notice that `providedIn: 'root'` has an instance per application while `providedIn: 'platform'` shares an instance. If you increment the platform counter from one application, you don't see changes in the other application right away because there's nothing to trigger change detection in the second application. Try incrementing either counter in the second application to see the changes caused by the first.